# php - local cache for Google Cloud Storage media

Tags: php, caching, video-streaming, google-cloud-storage

We want to store a few TBs of video files on Google Cloud Storage, but our webservers which will serve the videos to visitors are dedicated servers in our datacenter.
To reduce the costs for outbound Google Cloud traffic we want to cache as much video files as possible locally on the webservers. A cronjob will delete the oldest files (atime) in the cache if needed.

When a visitor request a video file which is not in the local cache, we start to download it from GCS using the stream wrapper feature of [google/cloud](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.56.0/storage/storageclient?method=registerStreamWrapper) and a combination of fopen, fread and fwrite to the local cache file. We also ensure that the script finished via [ignore_user_abort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php), even if the user aborts the playback. With this solution it is possible to send the video to the client and to save it locally simultaneously. The next request regarding this video will use the local cache file.

This works fine as long as the player does not support seeking, but we also want to provide seeking capability via HTTP_RANGE headers which will result in clients which will request only a partial content. Seeking to the right position of the video file in GCS works and seeking to the right position of the locally cached video file also works. What I need is a solution to create the locally cached video file step by step, depending on the requested partial content. As long as the requested range is not available in the local file, we download the partial content of the GCS file and write it to the local file. We have to mark the successfully cached parts and keep downloading the parts from GCS until the local file is complete. But I don't know how to share the information which parts are locally available between all the single HTTP-request. I feel that all these single request to the same video file with many different ranges from different clients sound like trouble... Any thoughts about this?

Comment: Essentially what you're trying to do is build your own CDN. Instead of doing that, why not use a CDN that already exists? GCP has a CDN component, and CGS works as a compatible backend with other 3rd party CDNs like Fastly.

Comment: @Sammitch can you post your comment as an answer?

Comment: this would also create additional costs for traffic, this is why we are looking for a solution which runs on our servers.